# angular 5 routing with custom pattern

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I develop a web application based on angular 5 that has about 100 legacy routes. All of them start with `/home`. e.g.

```
/home/financial-category-100
/home/banking-204
/home/508-accountant
/home/jobs-in-location
```

I should redirect all of them one by one to their new destinations.

What is the best practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i understand your issue,you can use matcher and urlSegment in your angular application and you can check and match your url with your desired pattern.

this link may help you: 
https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

github sample project:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12972